# How to integrate a pod library in an iOS Capacitor Plugin?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I want to use an external library named [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket) in my own iOS Capacitor plugin:

[image]

In the Podfile, I have:

```
require_relative '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios/scripts/pods_helpers'
platform :ios, '13.0'
use_frameworks!
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

def capacitor_pods
  pod 'Capacitor', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
...
  pod 'CapacitorGoodipClient', :path => '../../../client-capacitor'
end

target 'App' do
  capacitor_pods
  pod 'SwiftSocket', :git => 'https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket.git', :branch => 'master'
end

post_install do |installer|
  assertDeploymentTarget(installer)
end
```

When I compile, I receive the error "No such module 'SwiftSocket'". What am I doing wrong? I have done "ionic cap sync ios", "pod deintegrate", "pod install", "pod update".

My question could be formulated in a more generic way: What is the process to integrate a third-party library in a Capacitor plugin for the iOS platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two files involved, the Podfile and the .podspec file. This second file includes "dependency" which is not part of the Podfile.

The solution consists in adding

```
s.dependency 'SwiftSocket'
```

in the .podspec file (not in the podfile). More explanations [here](https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037704753-Capacitor-Plugin-Development-Adding-iOS-podfile-dependencies).